# For which $c$ is $\pi^c$ know to be irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

> For which $c$ is $\pi^c$ know to be irrational?

[Clearly](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788) $\pi$ is irrational and it is [known that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294621/homework-8th-grader-pi2-is-irrational) $\pi^2$ is irrational. However I believe it is not known if $\pi^{1/\pi}$ is irrational. This made me wonder what the full range of values $c$ is for which $\pi^c$ is known to be irrational.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not only $\pi^2$, it is in general known that if $0<c\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $\pi^c$ is irrational. Let $c=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are positive integers. If $\pi^{\frac{p}{q}}$ was rational then $\pi^p=(\pi^{\frac{p}{q}})^q$ would be rational as well. But this would imply that $\pi$ is a root of $x^p-\pi^p\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ which would contradict that $\pi$ is trancendental.

Comment: Are there *any* irrational values of $c$ for which it is known that $\pi^c$ is irrational?

Comment: Not sure. This is obviously a harder question.

Comment: True.  I guess it's a part of this question too.

Comment: Yes. There is no classification of all such values of $c$, that is for sure. Maybe there are concrete examples though.

Comment: Obviously you can just take the logarithm with base pi of any positive irrational number you want - you will obtain the desired $c$. Also, this is a characterizarion of all such numbers. The question is whether some of these numbers have some specific properties e.g. they are rational.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\A{\mathbb A}$You can use the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) to construct lots of such numbers:

> If $α_j\in\A$ are distinct algebraic numbers, then the exponentials $e^{α_j}$ are linearly independent over $\A$.

Now chose $α_2=0$ and $a\neq0$ in such a way that $α_1=a\ln\pi$ is algebraic. Then 1 and $e^{α_1}=\pi^a$ are independent over $\A$, i.e. $\pi^a$ is transcendental and thus irrational.

**Note:** Dunno whether $\ln\pi$ is algebraic or not, at least that theorem does not contradict it because we know $\pi\in\A$: Assuming $\ln\pi\in\A$ would just yield 1and $\pi$ were independent over $\A$, hence no contradiction.

Comment: That's a nice argument.

Comment: Ya, but we know nothing about $\ln\pi$, or do we? Thus we don't know what $a$ looks like.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735957/is-log-2-pi-rational Exactly as you say.